# Fail to destroy session and cookies in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, logout

Currently I am using the following code to log users out.

```
session_start();    
setcookie("u", "", time() - 999999);
setcookie("i", "", time() - 999999);
setcookie(session_name(),"",time()-999999);
session_destroy();
```

`$_COOKIE['u']` and `$_COOKIE['i']` are used to automatically log in users.

My problem is when I put this logout file directly under the web directory (i.e. `www/`), it works very well. However, when I put it in the secondary directory (i.e. `www/includes/`) or combined these codes with other PHP pages (i.e. change password and then log user out) in `includes` folder, user is not able to log out successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your cookies are being set on different paths. The 4th parameter is the domain path and the 5th is the domain.

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

It's a good idea to explicitly set these when working with cookies.